# Return a specific field using ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    client_name = models.CharField('Nom et prénom', max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name

class OtherInfos(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    client_name = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client_detail = models.TextField('détails', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.client_name)

class information(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    info_name = models.ForeignKey(patientlist, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    info_data = models.TextField('More info', blank=True)
    info_evolution = models.ForeignKey(OtherInfos, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.info_name)
```

Hello everyone,

I have these 3 tables :

a "Client" can have multiple "information" and "OtherInfos", and i would like to show all data in one html page, i managed to do 90% of it using Foreignkey where i can get "information" and "Client" data in the html page, but it didn't work with "OtherInfos", any suggestions please ?

thank you

Comment: what is the issue you having.

Comment: @RahulKP problem is i can't get "client_detail" data of specific Client using the foreignkey... Hope it's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that the uuid primary key change from one table to another even though it's the same Client, so when i try to do queries, it finds none, so what i did is i used AutoSlugField as primary key in all models :

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='NAME')
```

since all tables have the same 'NAME', that way i didn't need Foreignkeys...

Answer (score 0):

You can access data in this way

```
{% for info in information %}
      {{ info }}
     {% for other_info in info.info_evolution_set.all %}
         {{ other_info }}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is the pattern for it, you can add the third model to it, good luck

Comment: Sorry hashem, but it didn't work, i would like to get data from "client_detail" field using "info_evolution" foreignkey ...

Comment: This only for example how you can access nested relationship, but you should change the field to what you want to show